# Configuration of AWS with Sequel Pro

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, sequelpro

I am using Sequel Pro 1.1.2 in MacOS Mojave, when trying to configure the AWS database instance getting error as 
" Unable to connect to host vinay-awsdb.cinbpy8tpejb.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com, or the request timed out.
Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10 seconds).
MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'vinay-awsdb.cinbpy8tpejb.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (4)"

In the standard connection mac for Sequel Pro,I am entering the following:

**Name**: (used my instance name which is vinns, and also tried leaving it with the default of 'optional')
**Host**:vinay-awsdb.cinbpy8tpejb.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com

**Username**: (used my master user name)
**Password**: (used my master users password)

**Database**: (used database name mydbname, and also tried leaving it with the default of 'optional')
**Port**:3306

I am not able to connect.
I also tried by changing the **Inbound rules** to anywhere and increased connection timeout to 60 but did not worked

Comment: do you have an EC2 instance, or just you have RDS? if you have EC2 instance can you connect to your RDS from it?

Comment: yes i have EC2 instance running and RDS too, i did not tried to connect from EC2, cant we connect directly from RDS?

Comment: you should be able to, is your ssl certificate enabled? if yes you have to add ssl on the connection

Comment: this link might be helpfull for you https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=154817